# how to traverse xsd with its childs and format using python

Tags: python, xsd, xml-parsing, code-conversion

I have a requirement to get a report of a large list of XSDs, listing the complexType, minOccurs, maxOccurs, nillable, restrictions, enum values in tabular format. In essence its like transforming the xsd defination in a tabular format. My XSDs are having several childs, and each child is again having childs. So doing it manually is not only boring, but also error prone. With my limited python knowledge I am not able to come up with a solution, so need your help.

If anyone has tried something similar, or have thought how to get this done, please share your inputs. If you can point to some useful text/code, it will help a lot.

Thanks.